# SQL UPDATE QUERY LOGIC

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Declare @identifier nvarchar(100),
        @identifier_New nvarchar(100)
Declare identifier cursor for  
    select distinct Identifier01 
    from update_rules 
    where Identifier01 is not null 
          and  Vendor='Bloomberg' 
          and [Geneva Code]='Geneva77'

open identifier

    fetch next from identifier into @identifier

    while @@fetch_status=0
    begin
        set @identifier_New=upper(substring(@identifier,2,len(@identifier)-2))

        if exists(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name='investment' and column_name=@identifier_New)
        begin
            update i set i.[BBG Final Identifier]=case when u.Identifier01=@identifier then   @identifier_New    end
            FROM investment i,update_rules u
            where isnull(i.AType,'0')=isnull(u.[Asset Type],'0') and
                  isnull(i.IType,'0')=isnull(u.[Investment Type],'0') and 
                  isnull(i.Under_AType,'0')=isnull(u.[Under Lying Asset Type],'0') and 
                  isnull(i.Under_IType,'0')=isnull(u.[Under Lying Investment Type],'0') and
                  u.Vendor='Bloomberg' and u.[Geneva Code]='Geneva77'
        end
        fetch next from identifier into @identifier
    end
close identifier
deallocate identifier
```

I am getting an error her

```
update i set i.[BBG Final Identifier]=case when u.Identifier01=@**identifier** then   @identifier_New    end
    FROM investment i,update_rules u
```

Comment: This looks like SQL Server.  You should tag the question appropriately.

Comment: Can you please format your code so it is readable and update your question with the actual error message? We have no way of helping you with an unclear/unreadable question.

Comment: @user3751161, if Identifier01 is not equal to the identifier variable, your code will try to update it to be NULL: is that really what you expect? That would cause an error if the [BBG Final Identifier] column does not allow NULLs ...

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
       update i set i.[BBG Final Identifier]=case when u.Identifier01=@identifier then   @identifier_New    end
        FROM investment i, update_rules u
        where isnull(i.AType,'0')=isnull(u.[Asset Type],'0') and
              isnull(i.IType,'0')=isnull(u.[Investment Type],'0') and 
              isnull(i.Under_AType,'0')=isnull(u.[Under Lying Asset Type],'0') and 
              isnull(i.Under_IType,'0')=isnull(u.[Under Lying Investment Type],'0') and
              u.Vendor='Bloomberg' and u.[Geneva Code]='Geneva77';
```

First, you should use explicit `join`s, instead of implicit joins in the `where` clause.  SQL Server only allows an update from one table, so you don't use a table alias on the assignee side of `set`.

Try writing the query like this:

```
update i
    set [BBG Final Identifier] = (case when u.Identifier01 = @identifier
                                       then @identifier_New
                                  end)
    from investment i join
         update_rules u
         on isnull(i.AType,'0') = isnull(u.[Asset Type],'0') and
            isnull(i.IType,'0') = isnull(u.[Investment Type],'0') and 
            isnull(i.Under_AType,'0') = isnull(u.[Under Lying Asset Type],'0') and 
            isnull(i.Under_IType,'0') = isnull(u.[Under Lying Investment Type],'0')
    where u.Vendor='Bloomberg' and u.[Geneva Code]='Geneva77';
```

Comment: update i
    set [BBG Final Identifier] = (case when u.Identifier01 = @identifier
                                       then i.@identifier_New